# Angular Materials Mat Tab Group / Mat Tab width behavior

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-7

I implemented Angular Material mat tabs and mat tab group according to the Angular documentation, but I'm running into an issue when I hit tab two then back to tab one.  The sizing, for a few moments gets large for the first tab and then goes back to normal:

On tab two and hit tab one
[image: On tab two and hit tab one]

A few moments later after hitting tab one it goes back to normal
[image: A few moments later after hitting tab one]

The code is straightforward:

```
<div *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()">
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="1000ms">
    <mat-tab label="Real Time Market Info"> 
        <app-stock-monitor></app-stock-monitor>
        <app-sectors></app-sectors>
        <app-news></app-news>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Market Predictor"> TBD </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to disable ripple (disableRipple)

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="1000ms" disableRipple>
```